# wordpress adding strange core files over 10GB worth, how do I remove them?

Tags: php, wordpress, coredump

Our wordpress installation just started to create a LOT of core files, each over 100MB and they have taken over my host.

What are they and how do I remove them?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://forums.modx.com/index.php?action=thread&thread=35460&i=1) forum post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your server crashes and the core files are saved.

> I looked around for possible solutions and found more WordPress bloggers reporting this issue in the WordPress forums. I learnt that these are called Core Dump files and Wikipedia says core dump records the working memory of a computer program usually when the program crashes. Core dumps are often used to diagnose or debug errors in computer programs.
>
> In these forums some people advised we can delete these files and save space after backing up all files and database. Some advise the core files can be read using GDB, the GNU Project debugger. I am not sure if I should delete these files and maybe you can help.
>
> I understand that these files are hosted on our server to keep a record of useful data when the site crashed on a particular day, but I wonder if any hosting engineer is debugging this data or diagnosing why the server or unstable processes crashed or terminated.

http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2009/03/wordpress-core-dump-files/

Your installation or server may be the issue. Check the error_log for more info.

Also may check http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/wordpress-generating-core-dumps.

Comment: Thanks, we have just moved to a new hosting environment and I will check.